# Postfix: require valid sender address

Tags: postfix

Few days ago I received a message with `""@smtp.enta.net` as the sender in both the `From:` and `Return-Path` headers. Postfix accepted that email and transport it to dovecot.

Is it possible to configure Postfix to require a valid sender address (or at least a valid looking sender) or can I  block emails without username before the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol?

Headers of that message:

```
Return-Path: <""@smtp.enta.net>
Delivered-To: <root@example.com>
Received: from mail.example.com by mail.example.com (Dovecot) with LMTP id
 Q7XVJrXy3lYYdQAAfPZOvw for <root@example.com>; Tue, 08 Mar 2016 16:41:41 +0100
Received: by mail.example.com (Postfix, from userid 109) id 9BA2320826; Tue,  8
 Mar 2016 16:41:41 +0100 (CET)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on mail.example.com
X-Spam-Level: *
X-Spam-Status: No, score=1.7 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,FROM_NO_USER,
 HDRS_MISSP,HELO_MISC_IP,RDNS_NONE autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
 version=3.4.0
Received-SPF: None (no SPF record) identity=mailfrom;
 client-ip=171.233.198.106; helo=[171.233.198.106];
 envelope-from=@smtp.enta.net; receiver=root@example.com 
Received: from [171.233.198.106] (unknown [171.233.198.106]) by
 mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0CB112081D for
 <root@example.com>; Tue,  8 Mar 2016 16:41:39 +0100 (CET)
From: ""@smtp.enta.net
To: root@example.com
Subject: New voice mail message from 02083469819
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="3MwIy2ne0vdjdPXF"
Message-Id: <20110309073823.D3DD1B57DC5@smtp3.enta.net>
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 22:41:29 +0700
X-Evolution-Source: 1455535742.15855.5@thinkpad.example.local
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but this may be an actual RFC-compliant email-address (although probably invalid anyway) which would explain why postfix accepted it ?

Comment: I understand that this email ``""@smtp.enta.net`` is RFC-compliant but how write a rule to block such email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PCRE table and put it in smtpd restriction

```
# /etc/postfix/empty.pcre
/^""@/    REJECT
```

and in the main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/empty.pcre,
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/empty.pcre
    ... other restrictions ...
```